# Android Studio emulator extended controls location screen not loading

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, location

today I was trying to use location spoofing from adnroid emulator extended controls panel, but unfortunatelly it loads static map image with "raw" input that does not work anyway. I tried invalidating android studio cache, restarting OS, wiping AVD, deleting and setting up new AVD, updating emulator. None of these works. Yesterday it worked perfectly, today I can't get it to work. I can't even find similar problem on Google.

Here is info from "About Android Studio" tab:

```
Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 5, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Statistic, com.intellij.marketplace, org.jetbrains.kotlin, io.aesy.regex101, org.intellij.RegexpTester, com.developerphil.adbidea
```

And the location screen from extended controls:
[Location screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBWxb.jpg)

Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new API key for your app and make sure to update your API key in your code, and it work like a charm

Comment: What do you mean by an API key? Google Maps key? I think that emulator extended controls should be independent of in-app keys.

Comment: Sample API Key AIzaSyBH4FHZtdVm03iCh8AO0_ZB0Qguuejc7ah